# How to distinguish following two of "rather" meanings in sentence?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, word-order, word-difference

How to know the word **"rather"** is meaning  **to some degree** or **excessively** in a sentence?

They seem make sense to understand as any one of those two meanings in some examples below.

eg:

> It's rather(meaning **to some degree** or **excessively** ?) expensive.
>
> I rather(meaning **to some degree** or **excessively** ?)  think he was telling the truth.

And how to use **rather** when I want to express exactly **"to some degree"** or **"excessively"** in a sentence?

[image]

and another dictionary:

[image]

Comment: Replace "rather" with the word "somewhat" in the examples in the first definition and replace "rather" with the word "extremely" in the second definition to help understand the two different usages of "rather".

Comment: Question have been updated and more appropriate.

Comment: Cross-post of https://english.stackexchange.com/q/373437/64632

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the first dictionary entry, I don't accept their distinction between definitions 1 and 2. As far as I'm concerned, the two examples for the second definition both mean **to some degree**, which matches the first definition. If you wanted to make it clear that you meant **excessively**, you would have to add the word **too**:

> It's rather **too** expensive
>   He's rather **too** young to marry

Looking at the second dictionary entry, the use of **rather** before an opinion verb merely means that you hold the opinion **to some degree**, and one could do this in order to be polite. It does not, however, imply that you disagree with what somebody else said.

For examples where you are using **rather** to contrast two differing views, see the MORE EXACTLY and PREFERENCE section of the [Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/rather) definition.

Comment: Question have been updated.
how to use rather when I want to express exactly "to some degree" ?